# XSLT transforming is throwing error

Tags: xslt

I've xml as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
 <AllResidentAndUnitInfo xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 i:type="ResidentsByUnitInfo" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FSRSchema">
    <BillingAddresses>
      <BillingAddress>
        <billing_address1>Some address</billing_address1> 
        <billing_address2 /> 
        <billing_city>Gilbert</billing_city> 
        <billing_country i:nil="true"/> 
        <billing_dtmmodified>2010-12-08T01:37:41+05:30</billing_dtmmodified> 
        <billing_state>AZ</billing_state> 
        <billing_zipcode>23233</billing_zipcode>            
      </BillingAddress>
      <BillingAddress>
       <ResidentsByUnitInfoPropertyUnitBillingAddress>
        <billing_address1>Some address</billing_address1> 
        <billing_address2 /> 
        <billing_city>Gilbert</billing_city> 
        <billing_country i:nil="true"/> 
        <billing_dtmmodified>2010-12-08T01:37:41+05:30</billing_dtmmodified> 
        <billing_state>AZ</billing_state> 
        <billing_zipcode>23233</billing_zipcode> 
       </ResidentsByUnitInfoPropertyUnitBillingAddress>
      </BillingAddress>
      ....

</AllResidentAndUnitInfo>
```

I'm transforming into another xml format in C# using the XslCompiledTransform,

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
   xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt'
   xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' exclude-result-prefixes='msxsl  
   i' version='1.0'>
<xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>
<xsl:template match='/AllResidentAndUnitInfo/BillingAddresses/BillingAddress'>
    <Root>
      <Address1>..</Address2>   
              ...
    </Root>
</xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting the error "Token Text in state Start would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment." I understood the problem is with the i:nil attributes in the xml. Eventhough I included the namespace of them in XSLT still i'm getting the error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I'm getting the error "Token Text in state Start would result in an
>   invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is
>   set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want
>   to write an XML fragment." I understood the problem is with the i:nil
>   attributes in the xml. Eventhough I included the namespace of them in
>   XSLT still i'm getting the error.

**No. The problem is that the result isn't a well-formed XML document** and thus the `XmlWriter`, involved in producing the final serialization of the result tree to text, raises this exception.

**Really, in your result you have two `Root` elements** and none of them has a parent element.

You need to produce a well-formed document, or change the **[ConformanceLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.conformancelevel.aspx)** setting for the `XmlWriter` to `ConformanceLevel.Fragment` or `ConformanceLevel.Auto`.

**To create a wellformed output, just add**:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <top>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </top>
</xsl:template>
```